# phantomjs binary not found in Docker image, but it's there?

Tags: docker, npm, phantomjs

I have the following simple Dockerfile just to test installing PhantomJS

```
FROM tomcat:8.0.52-jre8-alpine
# NPM & PhantomJS
# 2.11 actually installs 2.1.1
ENV PHANTOM_VERSION="2.1.16"
RUN apk update \
  && apk add --update tar curl nodejs \
  && npm --version \
  && npm install phantomjs-prebuilt@${PHANTOM_VERSION} --phantomjs_cdnurl=https://bitbucket.org/ariya/phantomjs/downloads \
  && ls -al /usr/local/tomcat/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs \
  && ln -s /usr/local/tomcat/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs /usr/bin/phantomjs \
  && echo "PhantomJS binary: `which phantomjs`" \
  && `which phantomjs` --version
```

and I get this when I try to build an image.

```
PhantomJS binary: /usr/bin/phantomjs
/bin/sh: /usr/bin/phantomjs: not found
The command '/bin/sh -c apk update   && apk add --update tar curl nodejs   && npm --version   && npm install phantomjs-prebuilt@${PHANTOM_VERSION} --phantomjs_cdnurl=https://bitbucket.org/ariya/phantomjs/downloads   && ln -s /usr/local/tomcat/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs /usr/bin/phantomjs   && which phantomjs   && `which phantomjs` --version' returned a non-zero code: 127
```

And if I indeed run the container, and execute

```
$ phantomjs
```

I also get `not found`. I see the binary, and the link, there.

Why?

Comment: Is the binary actually executable? Also, I've seen this for compiled languages where dynamic requirements are not present. Even though the binary you requested to run is present, and indeed executable, when it tries to find a library, it just dies and reports that it could not be found.

Comment: yes it's a binary, and it's executable that is, has rwx-r-xr-x perms. So it may be the "can't find library" part that hosing it up. But shouldn't the installer handle this?

Comment: You would think so. I know that in golang, this can be caused by having a different goroot. When you do the npm install, try adding the -g for global and see if it makes any difference.